# How spring aop Proxy injection exactly works?

Tags: spring, concurrency, aop, autowired, spring-aop

I have the following example, it works in a different way that it supposed to be. "Actually how I think that I suppose" So thats I was doing this question.

I have these 2 classes

```
public class Person {

    private String randomId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    //gettet setter
}
```

And the service

```
public class Service {


    Person person;


    @Autowired
    public void setPerson(Person p){
        this.person=p;
    }

    public void execute(){
        System.out.println(person.getRandomId());
        Thread.sleep(10000L); //to simplify I've removed try catch
        System.out.println(person.getRandomId());
    }
}
```

In spring (and the corresponding annotation tag)

```
<bean id="Person" class="com.test.Person" scope="session">
    <aop:scoped-proxy/>
</bean>

<bean id="mySingletonBean" class="com.test.bo.Service" />
```

The problem is when I execute this in different browsers (B1 and B2), No matter what I always get the following pattern

Supposing random generated as B1=tttt and B2=bbbb
I ***always*** get the output

tttt
bbbb
tttt
bbbb

I've thought that I should receive an output like 
tttt
bbbb
bbbb
bbbb

But no, I don't understand how spring manages to give me the output above ()

Comment: Why do you expect the latter? You don't change the value of the randomId after it was created, so for each session the value stays the same as it was generated. Since you have 2 sessions, you will see those 2 values outputted twice.

Comment: But I'm using a singleton, and I'm replacing the session bean with this.person=p;..........person is an attribute of the singleton, not the session.

Comment: Or I'm having some kind of copy of the singleton bean for each session?

Comment: When I say, singleton I'm referring to <bean id="mySingletonBean" class="com.test.bo.Service" />

Comment: The service is a singleton, but the person which you get injected is a scoped proxy, which means every session has it's own instance and the proxy makes sure, the the method calls are redirected to the correct instance. So basically the object which you have injected in the person field is not a person object, but a proxy of Spring. And then you have a person bean for each session and the proxy directs to the correct object.

Comment: So, If I want to avoid this behaviour, Should I make a copy of the object, not a reference.